# Setting fonts with iTextSharp issue

Tags: itext

All,

I am trying to fill in an existing PDF and cannot change the font.

```
        var filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pdf"];
        var reader = new PdfReader(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + filename);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
        {
            foreach (var key in reader.AcroFields.Fields.Keys)
            {
                stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(key, "textsize", 8.0f, null);
                stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(key, "textfont", BaseFont.HELVETICA, null);
                stamper.AcroFields.SetField(key, "some value");
            }
        }
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

What am I missing?  When I compile this code, it blows up on the 'textfont' line of code and is saying "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont'".

Still learning this stuff.

Help!

Answer (score 4):

In your code you set

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(key, "textfont", BaseFont.HELVETICA, null);
```

`AcroFields.SetFieldProperty` for the property "textfont" expects a value of type  `BaseFont`.

But `BaseFont.HELVETICA` is not a specific `BaseFont` instance, it is the *name* of a specific base 14 font, a `string` constant.

Thus, you get that exception at runtime when iTextSharp tries to use the `string` value you give it as `BaseFont` value.

You can retrieve a `BaseFont` instance for Helvetica using e.g.

```
BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

and use it instead of `BaseFont.HELVETICA` in your `SetFieldProperty` call.